# Insert text in the middle of a dynamic div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I insert text in the middle of text?

This is my code:

```
<div class="MyText"> some content some dynamic dontent. my color is BLUE. some content </div>
```

Here I need to change the Value "Blue" to any other color by Jquery. Other Content in the div is come dynamically, So Apart from html(), append(), is there any way to fill it like php ?

Here we can do it via php like this

```
 <div class="MyText"> some content some dynamic dontent. my color is <?php echo("blue") ?>. some content </div>
```

Can we do it in Jquery/ Javascript ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you can use `.text()` to replace only the text contents of a node, however you will need to traverse the string (using Regex maybe) to determine where the word is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a SPAN tag with an id you can easily retrieve. Then you can change the content safely without having to resort to brittle manipulation.

```
<div class="MyText"> some content some dynamic dontent. my color is <span id="myColour">BLUE</span>. some content </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div class="MyText"> some content some dynamic dontent. my color is <span id="blue" style="display:none">BLUE</span>. some content </div>

 <button onclick="document.getElementById('blue').style.display='inline'">click me</button>
```

Sorry but i can't give you a jsfiddle of this but this will work.